# Backup automation with Crontab and Rsync work on local machine but doesn't on remote machine via ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, backup, rsync

I'm trying to make an automatic backup system that would sync 2 folders every 5 minutes with Rsync and Crontab both locally and remotely

**Both Machine is running**

Ubuntu Focal 20.04

**Folder source and destination**

My script are saved in the folder

```
/etc/local/<file-here>
```

Source: `/home/maurice/dev/`

Local Destination: `/media/maurice/SSD/dev/`

**Here is the script**

Local Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync -avz /home/maurice/dev/ /media/maurice/SSD/dev/
```

Remote Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync -e 'ssh -p 22' -avzp /home/maurice/dev/ maurice-Laptop.local:/home/maurice/dev/
```

**Here is my crontab File**

```
#Local Backup Script
*/5 * * * * maurice /etc/local/rsyncLocal_script
#Remote Backup Script
*/5 * * * * maurice /etc/local/rsync_script
```

Here is what work and what doesn't

**Working**

1.Local Backup work flawlessly

2.if i run the remote script manually it does work

3.i can ssh in both the local and remote computer without the need of a password the ssh key of both pc are added to `/home/maurice/.ssh/authorized_keys`

**Not Working**

1.Automation of the remote script

**What I tried**

1. Change the Remote script
   **From**

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync -e 'ssh -p 22' -avzp /home/maurice/dev/ maurice-Laptop.local:/home/maurice/dev/
```

**To**

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync -e 'ssh -p 22' -avzp /home/maurice/dev/ maurice@ipaddres:/home/maurice/dev/
```

But after that i really don't know what to do else

Thanks,

Comment: Is this your crontab? Or root's crontab? Or a system crontab?

Comment: This is a root crontab

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using the seven field layout for `crontab` entries in a file that expects only six. (See `man 5 crontab`)

Remove the entries from `root`'s crontab and put them into `maurice`'s `crontab`:

```
#Local Backup Script
*/5 * * * * /etc/local/rsyncLocal_script
#Remote Backup Script
*/5 * * * * /etc/local/rsync_script
```

There's no need to put these in a `root` crontab only for `cron` to then change its permissions to run as `maurice`. Just run them as `maurice` in the first place.

If that really isn't possible you need to use a system crontab (as distinct from root's crontab). For example, create a snippet file `/etc/cron.d/mybackups` and put the lines - including `maurice` -there.

In both cases you should consider capturing the output of the command. (If you'd had this you would have seen an error of the style `maurice: command not found`.) One option is to append error logging:

```
*/5 * * * * /etc/local/rsyncLocal_script >/tmp/rsyncLocal.log 2>&1
```

Personally, since both scripts run every five minutes, I'd put both commands into a single script,

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Backup locally
rsync -av /home/maurice/dev/ /media/maurice/SSD/dev/

# Backup remotely (if the server is available)
rsync -avz -e 'ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10' /home/maurice/dev/ maurice-Laptop.local:/home/maurice/dev/
```

Comment: Thanks for the help
how should i add the entries from root's crontab to maurice's crontab:

Comment: i also got this from /var/mail/root


`ssh: connect to host <ip-address-here> port 22: No route to host
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.3]`

Comment: "_how should i add the entries from root's crontab to maurice's crontab_" How did you add them to root's?

Comment: Your SSH error says your client doesn't know how to get to the remote server. That's nothing to do with crontab and everything to do with networking. You need to fix that first